# Looking for caveman style terms for the cardinal directions

Tags: synonyms

I started running a tabletop RPG campaign set in the distant future where mankind has degraded to a primitive hunter-gatherer society, and I'm looking for flavorful terms for NPCs to describe directions.

As research, I started watching the show "See" which has a similar premise, and they use the term "sun grave" to refer to west, because that's where the sun sets. And I love it! But what about the other directions? (I'm only midway through the first season of "See" and I haven't noticed them refer to another direction.)

East could be "away from the sun grave," but what about north and south? "Right of the sun grave?" That feels awkward to me. Is there another more primitive way of describing a perpendicularity like that, or perhaps another point of reference besides the sun?

Comment: Hello, P_M. ELU is not intended for questions about style, especially styles appropriate for specific genres. I suggest you try Writing.SE.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Naming questions aren't on topic on Writing SE either.

Comment: This question could possibly work here if it was asking about real archaic names for the directions (i.e. Old and Middle English words), though those are probably not the tone OP is looking for as the ones I found are from Latin.

Comment: This might be better asked over on [WorldBuilding](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/) given the intended usage.

Comment: World building SE is the best place for this

Comment: Invent a name for an earlier North Star (during the intended era).

Comment: 'Sun birth' for the east?

Comment: There are obvious characteristics of the north and south when viewed from some locations but it would depend on specific geography (e.g. the South is a cold place from New Zealand but not from Switzerland.) I agree this is way off-topic, but I'm not sure where it is on-topic.

Comment: "cardinal directions" is an abstraction that probably did not enter a caveman's mind. You might refer to the direction animal herds and flocks of birds take at the changing of the seasons. An agglutinative directional phrase would probably work well for your purposes.